# Code not calling Move constructor when compiled with clang and gcc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, c++11, clang

So, this compiles just fine on GCC, CLANG and MSVC but gives different output:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
 public:
    A() {
        cout << this << " def" << endl;
    }
    A(const A&) {
        cout << this << " copy" << endl;
    }
    A(A&&) {
        cout << this << " move" << endl;
    }
    A& operator= (const A&) {
        cout << this << " copy=" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    A& operator= (A&&) {
        cout << this << " move=" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout << this << " ~A" << endl;
    }
};

A f() { 
    A a;
    return a; 
}

int main(){
    A a = f();
}
```

With GCC and CLANG outputs:

- 0xbfad67cf def
- 0xbfad67cf ~A

While with MSVC out is as expected (C++11 standard):

- 0039FA3B def
- 0039FA3B move
- 0039FA3B ~A

So, code compiled with MSVC calls move constructor, while with GCC and CLANG move constructor is not called.
I also tried with optimizations disabled, and still get the same output. What is more strange is that when I change f() to return A(), move constructor is not called even on MSVC.

**Compiler versions:**

- **gcc:** version 4.7.2 (GCC)
- **clang:** version 3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final)
  Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu

**Platform:** Linux/ArchLinux

Comment: As was the case in C++03, copies can be completely elided, even if it changes the observable behavior. Moves just being special-case copies, it applies there too.

Comment: The claimed output is not what I see for the example you posted. Did the real code contain `return a;` instead of `return A();` in `f`?

Comment: @Daniel - Real code contains return a; but I also tried with return A() which avoided call to move constructor even on MSVC.

Comment: Next time please post matching code and output as I found this really confusing and therefore (and after another frustrating experience a few minutes earlier) didn't even dare to answer. Also, MSVC in case of `return A();` does perform the RVO, it does not perform the NRVO in case of `return a;`, although it should. Read about the difference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918312/what-rules-to-follow-for-a-function-to-use-nrv-optimization/5918369#5918369) and at the end, there is also a link for some MSVC-specific rules that describes when it applies the NRVO.

Comment: As already said, in certain circumstances, compilers are free (but no obliged) to elide calls to copy/move constructor. However, if (say, for research purposes) you want to disable this particular optimization, then GCC and Clang offers the compiler flag `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: Yes, it's for research and code demostration so your flag suggestion is a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is return value optimization

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

compiler optimized returned object not to be copyed than removed

Comment: Hm, so I cannot form my way in move constructor? Why such a behaviour if I really want to cathc all pointers insde the object and move them around to avoid deep copying?

Comment: The thing is that object is not being copyed. Look at your result. Compiler removed two attempts to copy your object:
1. when you returning by value
2. when you assining your object

Compiler understood that that copies are useless, and performed returning of a value direct to your variable.